# Matplotlib: how to plot with a specific hex color and a specific marker?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, markers

I need to produce a plot in which a line is plotted in Pigment Blue (`hex= #333399`) and with the `o` marker.

I know I can plot the line in Blue with the `o` marker by just calling:

`line1 = ax1.plot(x, myvalues,'bo-', label='My Blue values')`

**Question:** how should the line be changed if I wanted to still keep the marker and change the color from `b` to `#333399`?

Comment: Read this ;) http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change lots of things if you use the kwargs to [`plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) (which get passed to `Line2D`) instead of the shorthand 'bo-'. For example:

```
line1 = ax1.plot(
          x, myvalues,
          marker = 'o',
          linestyle = '-',
          markerfacecolor='#333399',
          markeredgecolor='k',
          label='My Blue values')
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use simply the color as a string like this,

```
line1 = ax1.plot(x, myvalues,'#333399', marker='o', label='My Blue values')
```